# how to play a video in vlc using php in local server

Tags: php, video, vlc

I'm completely new to php. i need to play a video in vlc using php in local server apache. i hav following files in /var/www : a.mp4 , sample.php nd vlc file which i copied from file system.

sample.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['request']))
{
echo system('vlc a.mp4');
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form  method="POST" action="sample.php" >

<br>
<input<?php ?> type="submit" name="request" value="play" />

</body>
</html>
```

please help..

Comment: Your intentions are not very clear. Do you want to embed a video in a client-side web page with PHP?

Comment: i want to play the video when play button is clicked in http://localhost/sample.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying. I guess that you are really trying to send the movie to the client and have their video player (be it VLC or whatever) play it. To do that, consider this: [Playing Videos in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp).

If you think about server actually trying to do what you are suggesting, get do some math and figure out the bandwidth required (I get about 20MB/s at 640x480 resolution with 16 bit color and 30 frames / s).

Comment: i want to play the video when play button is clicked in localhost/sample.php

Comment: try changing the method to 'GET' and the action to a.mp4 in your form. Depending on the browser, it should recognize the video and do what you are looking for.

Comment: But its showing You don't have permission to access /a.flv on this server.

Comment: That sounds like an Apache authorization error. I think that it locks /var/www down pretty tightly be default. Might want to check that out.